Loki query custom output
I have k8s container logs being sent to Grafana. I'm using the below query to get the logs which have a substring 'nfs'.
{container="check-node-dmesg-logs"} |~ "NFS" 
This is giving me an output like this -
2024-08-24 12:49:46.234 NFS mount error
2024-08-24 12:49:35.663 NFS mount error 
2024-08-24 12:49:25.092 NFS mount error
2024-08-24 12:49:14.519 NFS mount error 

I want the container name along with the logs in the output. Like this -
2024-08-24 12:49:46.234 check-node-dmesg-logs NFS mount error
2024-08-24 12:49:35.663 check-node-dmesg-logs NFS mount error 
2024-08-24 12:49:25.092 check-node-dmesg-logs NFS mount error
2024-08-24 12:49:14.519 check-node-dmesg-logs NFS mount error 

How can this be achieved?
Note: the container name can be found in the 'Fields' section of the log as shown in below.

